# DirectX Visual Studio templates don't Work

Tags: c++, visual-studio, directx, project-template

I installed a bunch of visual studio directx templates and none of them seems to work. They all throw an error like: "Error: this template attempted to load component assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Universal.TemplateWizards, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. For more information on this problem and how to enable this template, please see documentation on Customizing project templates." (This one in particular shows up for direct3d uwp Game template). I tried troubleshooting the existing .vstemplate file but I don't know whats wrong.

The template doesn't open, and I tried everything I know please help

[screenshot of said error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JKd1.png)
also "tamam" means okay

Comment: you probably need to re-install visual studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the [DirectX-VS-Templates](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates/wiki) you need to have the "Universal Windows Platform" workload installed with VS 2017 or VS 2019. It provides the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Universal.TemplateWizards` component.

This is true of both the UWP and Win32 templates in that GitHub project.

For the Direct3D UWP templates which use C++, you need to have the "Universal Windows Platform" workload and the "C++ Universal Windows Platform tools" optional component installed.

This is documented in the [readme](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates#vs-2017).

Comment: I'll see if I can figure out the smallest component id to put in the VSIX ``Prerequisites`` section so that it always includes the required wizard.

Comment: Note that for Win32 desktop projects, I've updated the template VSIX to not require the "Which SDK to use?" prompt so it shouldn't require the UWP component now unless you are using the UWP template.